# Integral mean value theorem- relate a point in the derivative to an integral

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

Let $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function s.t $f(a)=f(b)=0$ Prove that exists a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that
$$
|f'(c)| \ge \frac 4{(b-a)^2} \int ^b_a f(x) dx
$$
What we did:
We tried using the integral mean value theorem and then using LaGrange theorem, but ended with a sum of 2 points $(f'(y_1) + f'(y_2))$ in $[a,b]$ that we didn't know how to connect to $|f'(c)|$.

2nd try (using Newton Leibnitz, and then LaGrange theorem twice):
$|\frac 4{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b f(x)dx| =
|\frac 4{(b-a)^2}(F(a)-F(b))|= 
|\frac 4{(b-a)} \frac{(F(a)-F(b))}{b-a}| =
|\frac 4{(b-a)} f(c_1)|=
|\frac 4{(b-a)} \frac {(f(c_1)-f(a)) (c_1-a)}{c_1-a}|=
|\frac {4(c_1-a)}{(b-a)} \frac {(f(c_1)-f(a))}{c_1-a}|=
|\frac {4(c_1-a)}{(b-a)} f'(c)|$

our problem with this try is that we don't know how we can bound the last expression with f'(c)

Comment: Is $f$ nonnegative?

Comment: It doesn't matter if $f$ is nonnegative, because the integrals where $f$ is positive and negative can cancel out somewhat, but the maximal absolute value of the derivative will stay the same. So you might as well assume $f$ is nonnegative.

Comment: f' is continuous, so you can use intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Do you mean we should use the (regular) intermediate value theorem on f' or on f? Could you please elaborate a little... thx @achille hui

Comment: $f$ continuous differentiable means $f'$ continuous. Apply IVT to $f'$, you will find $f'(y_1) + f'(y_2) = 2 f'(\xi)$ for some $\xi$ between $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Comment: I posted a new try with a different direction now... I'll try checking out your suggestion now

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be an antiderivative (exist by [FTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)) of $f$. $F$ is twice differentiable by the given conditions.

By [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), there exists $c_1\in (a,b)$ and $c_2\in (a,b)$ such that $$F(b)=F(a)+(b-a)F'(a)+\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}F''(c_1)$$ and $$F(a)=F(b)+(a-b)F'(b)+\frac{(a-b)^2}{2}F''(c_2)$$

Subtract the equations using $F'(a)=F'(b)$, we have $2(F(b)-F(a))=\frac{(a-b)^2}{2}(F''(c_2)-F''(c_1))=\frac{(a-b)^2}{2}F''(c)$, last equality follows from [intermediate value property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) of derivative(doesn't even need to be continuous!). Therefore $|f'(c)|\geq f'(c)=\frac{4(F(b)-F(a))}{(b-a)^2}=\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b f(x)dx$